# Show all records in a list box

Tags: ms-access, filter, combobox, listbox

I'm currently making database that records who teachers and students are and when they are scheduled to have lessons. I have a list box taking data from a query that is being filtered by a combo box that is taking data from a table.

The filter is working but there is no way to display all the records from the query.

Is there a way to add an option to the combo box to pull all the records from the query through to the list box instead of the filtered few?

PS. Preferably by using embedded macros, VB if necessary

The row source of the combo box ('Teachers' is a table):

```sql
SELECT [Teachers].[TeacherID], [Teachers].[Forename], [Teachers].[Surname] 
FROM Teachers 
ORDER BY [Surname], [Forename], [TeacherID];
```

The row source of the list box ('TodayLessons' is a query, 'TeacherID' is using the criteria of the combo box on the form):

```sql
SELECT [TodayLessons].[LessonID], [TodayLessons].[SlotID], [TodayLessons].[Lesson Date], 
       [TodayLessons].[Lesson Time], [TodayLessons].[TeacherID], [TodayLessons].[StudentID] 
FROM TodayLessons 
ORDER BY [Lesson Date], [Lesson Time], [TeacherID];
```

Row source causing problem **(I've tried adding 'FROM Teacher' before 'UNION')**:

```sql
SELECT -99 AS TeacherID, "* All *" AS Forename, "" AS Surname UNION SELECT [Teachers].[TeacherID], [Teachers].[Forename], [Teachers].[Surname] FROM Teachers ORDER BY [Surname], [Forename], [TeacherID];
```

Comment: Please show the current `RowSource` of the listbox (edit your question and add it there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the listbox, you can do it like this:

Combobox, adding the "all" selection with a UNION query:

```sql
SELECT -99 AS TeacherID, "* All *" AS Forename, "" AS Surname
UNION
SELECT [Teachers].[TeacherID], [Teachers].[Forename], [Teachers].[Surname] 
FROM Teachers 
ORDER BY [Surname], [Forename], [TeacherID];
```

Listbox:

```sql
SELECT [TodayLessons].[LessonID], [TodayLessons].[SlotID], [TodayLessons].[Lesson Date], 
       [TodayLessons].[Lesson Time], [TodayLessons].[TeacherID], [TodayLessons].[StudentID] 
FROM TodayLessons 
WHERE (TeacherID = Forms!yourForm!cboTeachers)
   OR (Forms!yourForm!cboTeachers = -99)
ORDER BY [Lesson Date], [Lesson Time], [TeacherID];
```

The "OR" part of the WHERE clause makes all records True, if the special entry of the combobox is selected.

`-99` is just an arbitrary number, if TeacherID is an AutoNumber, you can also use `0` instead.

Comment: I keep getting an error: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression "(TeacherID = Forms!Today's Schedule!TodaySch-Teacher) OR (Forms!Today's Schedule!TodaySch-Teacher = -99)".

Comment: @Ben: with these form/control names, you must put them into [square brackets].: `Forms![Today's Schedule]![TodaySch-Teacher]`

Comment: Now I'm getting the error "Query input must contain at least one table/query" whenever I click on the combo box. The syntax error has stopped appearing whenever I open the form so I assume that that's fixed. The TeacherID is being stored as a long integer number if that helps (starting from 1).

Comment: Hmm. Please edit the question and add the current SQL rowsourc(es) that produce the error. @Ben

Comment: Might have found another way. The combo box code just adds another row to the combo box. The query 'TodayLessons' uses the TeacherID as criteria for what records to show in the list box. What if I just set the TeacherID for the new row to >0, then all the teachers with an ID above 0 (i.e. all of them) would appear. Then set the row source of the list box to the query. I've tried just typing >0 in place of -99 in the combo box row source but it keeps showing the error 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '>0'.'.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a subform instead of a listbox (but nicer to interact with as both a developer and and end user) then you can set `Filter on Empty Master` = No. this means that if the `Link Master Fields` are null that the child (subform) will show all the records instead of none of them.